# Position two elements within the same div under each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can position two elements under the same main div underneath each other efficiently with CSS (rather than writing individual CSS for each element). Essentially, I'm trying to make the search results page that google shows.

EDIT: I followed the suggestions in the comments, but the issue is without the float left, it seems as if the first 'article' is to the right of the search results, rather than actually being aligned underneath it.

```css
.logo img {
margin: 15px;
float: left;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: gray;
}

.searchbar .search {
 height: 30px;
 width: 650px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.searchbar .mic {
 position: absolute;
 left: 725px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.searchbar .tool {
 position: absolute;
 left: 760px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#menu {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 30px;
}

#menu li {
 float:left;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
}

#menu li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 20px;
 color: #696969;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.articles {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.articles .article {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 5px;
 float: left;
}

.articles .article .heading a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.articles .article .weblink a {
 color: green;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.articles .article .description  {
 color: #696969;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: 150px;
 
}

.footer a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #696969;
 display: inline;
 
}

.footer .feedback,
.footer .privacy,
.footer .terms {
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Search Results</title>
</head>


<body>

    <div class='logo'>
        <a href='www.google.com'><img src='https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/small-google-logo-png-transparent-background-600x200.png'
                alt='Google logo' height='35'></a>
    </div>

    <div class='searchbar'>
        <form>
            <input class='search' type='text' placeholder="Sample Google search results page">
            <img class='mic' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/716px-Google_mic.svg.png'
                alt='Google microphone' height='25'>
            <img class='tool' src='https://static.thenounproject.com/png/105498-200.png' alt='Google search tool'
                height='25'>
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul id='menu'>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>News</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Shopping</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Maps</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>More</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Tools</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class='results'>
        <p style='color: #696969; float: left; padding-left: 150px;'> About 127,000,000 results (0.64 seconds) </p>
    </div>

    <div class='articles'>
        <ul class='article'>
            <li class='heading'><a href='www.google.com'>With zero coding experience, artist building 180 webpages ...
                </a></li>
            <li class='weblink'><a href='www.google.com'>arstechnica.com/.../with-zero-coding-experience-artis... </a></li>
            <li class='description'>Jul 26, 2013 - 117 days ago, having never done any programming in her life,
                Jennifer Dewalt built her first webpage. The next day, she built another, and she ... </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class='article'>
            <li class='heading'><a href='www.google.com'>With zero coding experience, artist building 180 webpages ...
                </a></li>
            <li class='weblink'><a href='www.google.com'>arstechnica.com/.../with-zero-coding-experience-artis... </a></li>
            <li class='description'>Jul 26, 2013 - 117 days ago, having never done any programming in her life,
                Jennifer Dewalt built her first webpage. The next day, she built another, and she ... </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='logodown'>

    </div>

    <div class='footer'>
        <a class='help' href='www.google.com/#'>Help</a>
        <a class='feedback' href=www.google.com/#>Send feedback</a> <a class='privacy' href='www.google.com/#'>Prviacy</a>
        <a class='terms' href='www.google.com/#'>Terms</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: don't absolutely position them or float them (I see no need for either in this situation) and they will naturally appear under each other

Comment: I need them aligned to the left though, how can I achieve that then? If I don't float it, my 'articles' doesn't align to the left like it should.

Comment: Remove the margin and padding from the ul and li - Or just use div (or article) tags, you are also incorrectly using the ul tags - I would say if you want to continue using the ul tags, then each article should be an li (not new ul) - not each line of the result

Comment: Ok with your edit - if you don't want things to be on the right of the results - why float the results - you need to stop abusing floats and learn how to use them properly or clear them (although with css3 you shouldn't need to use them at all)

Comment: The results all align, but the first results ends up to the right of the page even though I'm not longer floating it. I think I made an edit to fix it, but I'm curious - without floating (for example the google logo and the search bar, how else would I align them into the same line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a class per article, just use a class `article`.

Also, the `float` & `position` were the problematic properties.

```css
.logo img {
margin: 15px;
float: left;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: gray;
}

.searchbar .search {
 height: 30px;
 width: 650px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.searchbar .mic {
 position: absolute;
 left: 725px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.searchbar .tool {
 position: absolute;
 left: 760px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#menu {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 30px;
}

#menu li {
 float:left;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
}

#menu li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 20px;
 color: #696969;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.articles {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.articles .article {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 5px;
 float: left;
}

.articles .article .heading a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.articles .article .weblink a {
 color: green;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.articles .article .description  {
 color: #696969;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: 150px;
 
}

.footer a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #696969;
 display: inline;
 
}

.footer .feedback,
.footer .privacy,
.footer .terms {
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Search Results</title>
</head>


<body>

    <div class='logo'>
        <a href='www.google.com'><img src='https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/small-google-logo-png-transparent-background-600x200.png'
                alt='Google logo' height='35'></a>
    </div>

    <div class='searchbar'>
        <form>
            <input class='search' type='text' placeholder="Sample Google search results page">
            <img class='mic' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/716px-Google_mic.svg.png'
                alt='Google microphone' height='25'>
            <img class='tool' src='https://static.thenounproject.com/png/105498-200.png' alt='Google search tool'
                height='25'>
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul id='menu'>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>News</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Shopping</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Maps</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>More</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href='www.google.com/#'>Tools</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class='results'>
        <p style='color: #696969; float: left; padding-left: 150px;'> About 127,000,000 results (0.64 seconds) </p>
    </div>

    <div class='articles'>
        <ul class='article'>
            <li class='heading'><a href='www.google.com'>With zero coding experience, artist building 180 webpages ...
                </a></li>
            <li class='weblink'><a href='www.google.com'>arstechnica.com/.../with-zero-coding-experience-artis... </a></li>
            <li class='description'>Jul 26, 2013 - 117 days ago, having never done any programming in her life,
                Jennifer Dewalt built her first webpage. The next day, she built another, and she ... </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class='article'>
            <li class='heading'><a href='www.google.com'>With zero coding experience, artist building 180 webpages ...
                </a></li>
            <li class='weblink'><a href='www.google.com'>arstechnica.com/.../with-zero-coding-experience-artis... </a></li>
            <li class='description'>Jul 26, 2013 - 117 days ago, having never done any programming in her life,
                Jennifer Dewalt built her first webpage. The next day, she built another, and she ... </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='logodown'>

    </div>

    <div class='footer'>
        <a class='help' href='www.google.com/#'>Help</a>
        <a class='feedback' href=www.google.com/#>Send feedback</a> <a class='privacy' href='www.google.com/#'>Prviacy</a>
        <a class='terms' href='www.google.com/#'>Terms</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit**: I added a small input and it is clearly not next to the first article.

**Edit 2**: You need to remove the `float` in the inline-style applied to the `result` paragraph:

```html
<p style='color: #696969; float: left; padding-left: 150px;'> About 127,000,000 results (0.64 seconds) </p>
```

Must become:

```html
<p style='color: #696969;'> About 127,000,000 results (0.64 seconds) </p>
```

Comment: When I do this, what occurs is that the first article is to the right of the search bar, rather than formatted below the searchbar in a vertical list.

Comment: Edited my post, but without the float & position properties, your articles will follow the vertical flow of the `block` elements.

Comment: For some reason, SO isn't showing what is shown in my IDE when I run the HTML (https://imgur.com/a/UVM7FBa)

Comment: Edited my answer with your html, but there's some css missing. Can you please edit your question with all the necessary sources ?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I added the CSS in, so it looks like what i'm seeing.

Comment: Edited my answer one more time :)